# Get the mouse position during drag and drop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, mouse, position

Does anyone know how to get the correct mouse position during a drag-and-drop operation in WPF? I've used `Mouse.GetPosition()` but the returned value is incorrect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Never mind, I've found a solution. Using `DragEventArgs.GetPosition()` returns the correct position.

Comment: Hi @J W GetPosition() takes IInputElement as parameter. What did you pass to this function?

Comment: @AFgone: I did it with DragEventArgs.GetPosition(this) or otherwise just the instance of whatever the event was bound to. Turned out to work as expected.

Comment: sorry for resurrecting this old thread, but: when I'm dragging over parts that are `AllowDrop = false`, then I don't get the `DragOver `-Event which is the only one to give me `DragEventArgs`

Answer (score 2):

DragOver handler is a solution for general situations. But if you need the exact cursor point while the cursor is not in droppable surfaces, you can use the GetCurrentCursorPosition method below. I refered [Jignesh Beladiya's post](http://jigneshon.blogspot.com/2013/11/c-wpf-snippet-reliably-getting-mouse.html).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

public static class CursorHelper
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

    public static Point GetCurrentCursorPosition(Visual relativeTo)
    {
        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
        return relativeTo.PointFromScreen(new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y));
    }
}
```